# "javax.crypto.ShortBufferException: Output buffer is not sufficient." when trying to encode a string with AES

Tags: java

When the application is run on my localhost, it works fine, but if I try to run it on remote Digital Ocean server, [this exception](http://freetexthost.com/owbdk3us0m) is thrown.

[Here](http://freetexthost.com/qifayzwe6s) you can find the whole code. This is the function that causes the exception:

```
public static String encode(String src, String key) {
    // This is the function that has the exception. I put it all inside try-catch because an exception here would mean the program cannot work at all

    try {
        SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key.substring(0, 16).getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(key.substring(0, 16).getBytes());

        CryptoCipher encipher;
        encipher = Utils.getCipherInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", getProps());

        byte[] input = src.getBytes();
        byte[] output = new byte[(input.length / 16 + 1) * 16];

        encipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k, iv);

        int updateBytes = encipher.update(input, 0, input.length, output, 0);
        int finalBytes = encipher.doFinal(input, 0, 0, output, updateBytes);
        encipher.close();

        return hexString(Arrays.copyOf(output, updateBytes + finalBytes));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }   
}
```

On localhost I use:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
Server built:   Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
Server number:  8.5.11.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.4.0-67-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

The server has this:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-1~bpo8+1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb 18 2017 05:56:46
Server number:  8.0.14.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.16.0-4-amd64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-1~bpo8+1-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Have anyone had that problem, or maybe any ideas what to check?

Comment: The reason is output array was too short. I don't actually remember where I took the formula to calculate it, but it seems to be wrong for this particular algorithms. I'll continue my researches later and will add an answer with correct formula.

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776237/alex-k, what is the resolution for this issue? I am also facing similar issue when test my code with java-17.

Comment: java.security.ProviderException: javax.crypto.ShortBufferException: Output buffer invalid

 at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.engineDoFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:408)
 at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
 at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.impl.AESGCM.decrypt(AESGCM.java:297)
 at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.impl.ContentCryptoProvider.decrypt(ContentCryptoProvider.java:279)